# Multiple Background Services in .NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-6.0, background-service, asp.net-core-hosted-services

Create Multiple Background tasks in .NET 6 which are independent to each other in functionality aspect and runs parallelly / simultaneously depending on the scheduled timings.
With  [Worker class template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/workers) i was able to create multiple Hosted / Background services and they are running as expected.

But `services.AddHostedService<Worker>();` will be taken as Singleton class & we need to resolve scoped dependency in order to make the service as scoped, followed the same from [scoped service document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/scoped-service).
As per the example in the above link, sample code looks like this,
Interface of Scoped service

```
  namespace App.ScopedService;
public interface IScopedProcessingService
{
    Task DoWorkAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken);
}
```

and the default implementation of the interface

```
namespace App.ScopedService;

public class DefaultScopedProcessingService : IScopedProcessingService
{
    private int _executionCount;
    private readonly ILogger<DefaultScopedProcessingService> _logger;

    public DefaultScopedProcessingService(
        ILogger<DefaultScopedProcessingService> logger) =>
        _logger = logger;

    public async Task DoWorkAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            ++ _executionCount;

            _logger.LogInformation(
                "{ServiceName} working, execution count: {Count}",
                nameof(DefaultScopedProcessingService),
                _executionCount);

            await Task.Delay(10_000, stoppingToken);
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the Background service implementation

```
namespace App.ScopedService;

public sealed class ScopedBackgroundService : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;
    private readonly ILogger<ScopedBackgroundService> _logger;

    public ScopedBackgroundService(
        IServiceProvider serviceProvider,
        ILogger<ScopedBackgroundService> logger) =>
        (_serviceProvider, _logger) = (serviceProvider, logger);

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation(
            $"{nameof(ScopedBackgroundService)} is running.");

        await DoWorkAsync(stoppingToken);
    }

    private async Task DoWorkAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation(
            $"{nameof(ScopedBackgroundService)} is working.");

        using (IServiceScope scope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope())
        {
            IScopedProcessingService scopedProcessingService =
                scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IScopedProcessingService>();

            await scopedProcessingService.DoWorkAsync(stoppingToken);
        }
    }

    public override async Task StopAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation(
            $"{nameof(ScopedBackgroundService)} is stopping.");

        await base.StopAsync(stoppingToken);
    }
}
```

and Program.cs would be something like follows

```
using App.ScopedService;

using IHost host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .ConfigureServices(services =>
    {
        services.AddHostedService<ScopedBackgroundService>();
        services.AddScoped<IScopedProcessingService, DefaultScopedProcessingService>();
    })
    .Build();

await host.RunAsync();
```

If i have another Background service, then which all code i can re-use and how do i resolve scoped service ?

Comment: I would say that after reading your question twice I still have no idea what is the problem) Can you please share some code or [mre]?

Comment: My question is "how do we create multiple scoped/Background services ?".

Comment: Completely the same way as you create one. What is the problem? =)

Comment: So you have a hosted service which creates a scope to resolve a scoped service and you want to resolve the scoped service multiple times and get a different instance each time? Could you share your code - at least conceptually - and what issue do you perceive with your current solution?

Comment: Let say i have 3 (or many) different worker services. So for each time when i create a new service which all common classes i can take  from this example   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/scoped-service

Comment: @Hariprasadkasavajjala if you find my answer useful, please mark it as accepted

Comment: Just edited My Question, could you please re-check my problem
@CherryQuery

Comment: Have you had a look at Hangfire? or is this on the wrong track? This is for running async, background recurring jobs etc

Comment: @GuruStron if my understanding is correct from the above example which i have posted, 
DefaultScopedProcessingService class is only to make the service in scope and nothing more than that. The actual implementation lies in the  ScopedBackgroundService class and if there's any new service, it should be implemented the same way but we use DefaultScopedProcessingService there also just to make the service in scope. Right?

Comment: @Hariprasadkasavajjala I would say that it is vice versa, the `ScopedBackgroundService`'s service job is to create a scope and call service which performs actual work. So the actual worker implementation is  in the `DefaultScopedProcessingService` (in this case it logs something every 10_000 milliseconds).

Comment: so in order to implement another service, what is the order of  the things should i follow?

Comment: One more concern from my side: You have a singleton and that sibgleton creates a scope for ita whole lifetime. So the scoped service that is injected also has, in practice, singleton lifetime. I'm just wondering why you need scoped lifetime at all under these circumstances.

Comment: Regardless though, you can do whatever work you like in ExecuteAsync. You don't need another scoped service if you need to use other scoped dependencies, you can just use the scope to resolve scoped services and use them directly. This may also be more natural, e.g. if the job runs every 30 seconds, you may want to create a scope for each run as opposed to having a single scope for the entire application lifetime as is the state in your example.

Answer (score 7):

You can create multiple services implementing IHostedService interface and then register them just like that:

```
builder.Services.AddHostedService<HostedServiceA>();
builder.Services.AddHostedService<HostedServiceB>();
builder.Services.AddHostedService<HostedServiceC>();
```

If you want to access scoped service inside the singleton the easiest way is to inject *IServiceScopeFactory* in constructor:

```
public HostedServiceA(IServiceScopeFactory serviceScopeFactory)
{
    _serviceScopeFactory = serviceScopeFactory ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(serviceScopeFactory));
}
```

and then you can access scoped services inside the methods by calling:

```
using var scope = _serviceScopeFactory.CreateScope();
var someScopedService = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<ISomeScopedService>();
var someOtherScopedService = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<ISomeOtherScopedService>();
```

Comment: In your example, is `HostedServiceA/B` meant to implement `IServiceA/B`? Is the lowercase of the `hostedServiceA` constructor a typo or intended?

Comment: nah, they don't mean to, bad examples from me and yes, there is a typo, thanks for noticing,
edited the answer

Comment: @CherryQuery from your example, i understood for every background service we need to implement a service & scope service too. is my understanding correct?

Comment: all you do is create custom interface like

public interface ISomeScopedService {
    void SomeMethod()
}


and create implementation for it, You also register the interface and implementation in startup and then u can access this service using IServiceScopeFactory as written above

Comment: I mean do i need to implement the interface for every new service or only one implementation is enough for all the services?

Comment: if each service has different methods then different interface for each implementation